# Proximity sensor windows phone 8.1 runtime

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Does proximity sensor in windows phone 8.1? I want to detect it but I can't find out any API can do that.

Answer (score -1):

I think [Windows.Networking.Proximity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.aspx) is what you want.

And check [this online video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/15) on channel 9 to learn how it works.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But I want to detect the presence of nearby objects not communicate between 2 devices. :(

Comment: No such API available. :( Seems it's only possible for Microsoft OEM to get such kind of API. Submit your idea or vote on same idea to https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform .

Comment: I am sad to hear that. Thank you :)